# Customizing Sections in Table of Contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, sectioning, koma-script, tocbasic

community,

I have received great help many times before on this platform and I really do hope that you can help me yet again! I'm trying to customize my ToC in such a way that things like the List of Figures and List of Tables:
1. appear in the ToC
2. are written in cursive
3. are as sections as close together as subsections/are as subsections not indented

The first two points I could manage, but the last one just doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={* Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{fancyref}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\KOMAoptions{toc=sectionentrydotfill}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listof{table}{\textit{List of Tables}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textit{List of Tables}}
\section*{\textit{List of Abbreviations}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textit{List of Abbreviations}}
\section{Test}
Text
\section{Test2}
Text2
\end{document}
\section*{\textit{Glossary}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textit{Glossary}}
 \section*{\textit{Declaration of Originality}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textit{Declaration of Originality}}
```

I have found a package that allows you to customize your ToC but I cannot really use it and it just produces errors all the time. I think it would be easiest to define a new section category (like 'nsection') that has a different baseline skip than the normal section (because I would very much like to keep that)

Thank you so much! If you need any more information, please let me know!

Edit: I have added more 'random' sections that are not their own function in LaTex in order to demonstrate that I want to be able to use 'nsection' for anything I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** (MWE in question and desired result are changed: usage of `nsection` not restricted to lists like LOF and LOT)

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}% loads and uses tocbasic!
\usepackage{xltxtra}% loads also fontspec
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={* Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{fancyref}

\KOMAoptions{
  toc=sectionentrydotfill,
  listof=totoc
}

\newkomafont{standardsection}{\Large}
\newkomafont{nsection}{\usekomafont{standardsection}\slshape}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\sectiontocdepth,%
  beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,%
  indent=0pt,%
  numwidth=1.5em,%
  entryformat=\usekomafont{sectionentry}\textsl%
]{section}{nsection}

\newcommand*\usensection{% define switch to nsection
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{1em plus 1pt}}% additional space in TOC before the first nsection entry
  \setkomafont{section}{\usekomafont{nsection}}%
  \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{nsection}{##1}{##2}}%
}
\newcommand*\usestandardsection{% define switch to standard section
  \setkomafont{section}{\usekomafont{standardsection}}%
  \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{section}{##1}{##2}}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\usensection% switch to nsection
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\addsec{List of Abbreviations}

\usestandardsection% switch to standard section
\section{Test}
Text
\section{Test2}
Text2

\usensection% switch to nsection
\addsec{Glossary}
\addsec{Declaration of Originality}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Original answer** (`nsection` only needed for lists like LOF and LOT)

Here is a suggestion using a new declared TOCStyleEntry `nsection` for the entries of LOF and LOT in TOC. Therefore `\addsectiontocentry` is redefined locally.

Note that KOMA-Script class `srcartcl` already loads package `tocbasic`. So do not load it again.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}% loads and uses tocbasic!
\usepackage{xltxtra}% loads also fontspec
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={* Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{fancyref}

\KOMAoptions{
  toc=sectionentrydotfill,
  listof=totoc
}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\sectiontocdepth,%
  beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,%
  indent=0pt,%
  numwidth=1.5em,%
  entryformat=\usekomafont{sectionentry}\textsl%
]{section}{nsection}
\BeforeTOCHead{%
  \addtokomafont{section}{\slshape}%
  \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{nsection}{#1}{#2}}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\section{Test}
Text
\section{Test2}
Text2
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If the changes should be restricted to lists with `owner=float` (LOT, LOF, etc), you can use:

```
\makeatletter
\doforeachtocfile[float]{% do for all lists with owner=float like LOF and LOT
  \BeforeTOCHead[\@currext]{%
    \addtokomafont{section}{\slshape}%
    \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{nsection}{##1}{##2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}% loads and uses tocbasic!
\usepackage{xltxtra}% loads also fontspec
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={* Caps}]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{fancyref}

\KOMAoptions{
  toc=sectionentrydotfill,
  listof=totoc
}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\sectiontocdepth,%
  beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,%
  indent=0pt,%
  numwidth=1.5em,%
  entryformat=\usekomafont{sectionentry}\textsl%
]{section}{nsection}
\makeatletter
\doforeachtocfile[float]{% do for all lists with owner=float like LOF and LOT
  \BeforeTOCHead[\@currext]{%
    \addtokomafont{section}{\slshape}%
    \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{nsection}{##1}{##2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\section{Test}
Text
\section{Test2}
Text2
\end{document}
```

Note that you will get the same result with

```
\BeforeTOCHead[lof]{%
  \addtokomafont{section}{\slshape}%
  \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{nsection}{#1}{#2}}%
}
\BeforeTOCHead[lot]{%
  \addtokomafont{section}{\slshape}%
  \renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{\addtocentrydefault{nsection}{#1}{#2}}%
}
```

Comment: I was trying to find a solution without using the KOMA macros in KOMA (terrible work), so nice to see what KOMA offers! `\BeforeTOCHead` patches **just locally** the `listof` commands, right? It is changing the toc title font ('Contents') as well. Purely educational and before I start digging myself, maybe you know how to check for a certain `listof` to not change the toc title font? Or how should one solve that with KOMA?

Comment: Yes, `BeforeTOCHead[<extension>]{\addtokomafont{section}{\slshape}}` changes the font settings for the section titles locally. The optional argument `<extension>`  can be used to do this for single lists or for lists of a special owner. See my answer. And thanks for the hint: I had overlooked that the font of the TOC title should not change.

Comment: thank you so much! this is all I ever wanted (and more!^^)

Comment: @esdd I have edited my original post and added more 'general' sections as well because I want to be able to use 'nsection' for any section I want, regardless of that section's status as a proper LaTeX function. Unfortunately, I haven't made that clear enough in the beginning!

Comment: @LajosH See my updated answer. But note that it is usually better to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @esdd your solution has worked perfectly! unfortunately, now it stopped working and I get the errors "Missing \endcsname inserted", "Extra \endcsname", "Extra \else", and "Extra \fi" -- I have reinstalled my TexStudio on another system, but I cannot seem to get rid of this issue... (I hope you see this and sorry for asking in a comment! I didn't know what to call the new question) -- I was using your updated MWE!

Comment: @LajosH You get this error with my example or with your code? With my code I can not reproduce the error neither. Which KOMA-Script version do you use?